# Application always asks for permission to access keychain

Tags: macos, xcode4

I have an application that stores username and password in the keychain. Everything was working fine when working on Xcode 3, I recently moved to Xcode 4 and now when I run the application, I get a prompt:

`Application wants to use your confidential information stored in keychain" in your keychain.`

After hitting always allow I see the application added to access control list of the keychain item, but I get every time I run the app.

Also after hitting Always allow again, I see that the access control has two instances of the same app. Seems like OS thinks this is a new application.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: How are you code-signing your app? (That's one of the most common reasons for this problem.)

Comment: I have to code sign set up in Xcode build settings, Under code sign I have selected a code signing identity to my Developer ID Application

Comment: Have you run a previous build on the same machine? Depending on the Designated Requirement (which depends on the version of Xcode 4 you use, if you're just sticking with the defaults), the Keychain may treat your old build and your new one as different apps, meaning your new build will pop up warnings if the old build had stored anything in the Keychain.

Comment: Yes, I have tried removing the keychain and adding (my app creates this keychain entry if not present) still I see the popup again and again. Even when I run the same .app again and again, I see it added more than once in ACL of keychain item. Is there something I should be  doing while signing my application ?

Comment: Another interesting thing that I just figured out is that when I try and code sign my application with a local generated certificate, it just works fine. If I try and do that same thing with the apple generated developer certificate, I see this strange behavior where I am prompted for permission to access the key chain again and again.

Comment: There are two possibilities here. One is that it's remembering the original DR (from your local cert). The other is that for some reason the DR you're using with your new cert doesn't actually accept that cert. It's plausible that if you're using a Developer ID with an older version of Xcode 4 and default signing rules you might get odd behavior. Especially if you don't have the appropriate Intermediate cert installed on your build machine. Can you post the actual codesign line that Xcode creates and runs (from your build output)?

Comment: Here is the code signing lineCodeSign "/Users/user1/MMMacBuilds/MAIN/Xcode0433/Debug/appName.app"
    cd /Users/user1/Projects/rnd/MAIN/MMMac/source/Application/Mac
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign c6b374edecf8fa950174c79a538bf3b2edf5d56b --entitlements "/Users/user1/MMMacBuilds/MAIN/Xcode0433/IntermediateBuildFiles/appName.build/Debug/appName.build/appName.xcent" "/Users/user1/MMMacBuilds/MAIN/Xcode0433/Debug/appName.app"

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is that your signature's designated requirement causes it to not accept itself as "the same app" as itself (for Keychain purposes).

One common cause for this—and I think it's yours—is using a Developer ID Application cert, with no designated requirement, and without the intermediate cert installed.

A standard Developer ID requirement looks like this:

```
designated => anchor apple generic and 
identifier \"com.example.appName\" and 
((cert leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] exists) or 
 (certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] exists and 
 certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] exists  and 
 certificate leaf[subject.OU] = \"1AZBYCXDW9V\" ))
```

If you want to construct this yourself, you have to replace the identifier with your bundle identifier and the subject.OU with the value from your cert. (If you double-click it in Keychain Access, it should be listed as the Organizational Unit.) Then you can add to "Other Code Signing Flags":

```
--requirements "=designated ..." (the whole mess from above)
```

However, a much better way to do this is to use Xcode 4.3.2 or later. If it recognizes that you're using a Developer ID Application cert, and can see the intermediate cert in the keychain, it will generate this by default.

Also, if you use the Archive Organizer in Xcode to "Export Developer ID-signed Application", instead of just using the build from your target directory, it will make sure to sign your app and any other enclosed signables, and it will test that everything is setup properly. (The failures are pretty cryptic—e.g., your "Choose a Developer ID to sign with" step may just have no choices, with a message in the syslog that has no useful information—but at least the fact that it failed or succeeded narrows down where your problem is.)

Either way, you need to download and install (on your build machine) the intermediate cert, called "Developer ID Certification Authority", from the "Developer ID Intermediate Certificate" link at the [Developer Certificate Utility](https://developer.apple.com/certificates/index.action) site.

One last thing: Even if this solves your problem running on your build machine, you really want to test on the oldest OS version you support. For example, the requirements compiled by Lion's codesign sometimes can't be parsed on Leopard, or sometimes even on Snow Leopard. If that happens… see [Gatekeeper vs. Leopard: an ongoing tale](http://fetchsoftworks.com/fetch/blog/gatekeeper-vs-leopard-an-ongoing-tale).

Comment: Thanks abarnert, that was a lot of great info. But looks like I found a resolution to this issue. I removed the code signing from UI in Xcode and added this as a command line step at the end of my build script. This seems to be working fine now, but really, thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: Nitin, can you share your resolution, I'm having the same issue with Xcode 6